# Xcode 6 Navigation bar weird

Tags: ios8, xcode6

```
I just upgraded my Xcode 5 project to Xcode 6 (clean install). But now with 2 viewControllers there is a problem: I try to hide the back button on 1 of them, it goes weird (see the pictures). 

I didn't change anything. Is it possible to fix this somehow?
```

http://i60.tinypic.com/2qd096v.png

http://i60.tinypic.com/npgv0y.png

There should be a back button on the register screen en the Sparks title shouldn't be there. If I press on the navigation bar it goes to the welcome screen again and from then on everything is back OK.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found a solution to this.

In the file where you push to the new Controller you have to set that it hides the back button.

controller.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];